# How to interface with Windows from MSP-EXP430F5529LP via USB, preferably from Energia?

Tags: serial-port, embedded, msp430

This may sound trivial, but I did not find a step-by-step guide. Energia has plenty of examples,
e.g. SerialCallResponseASCII

So the main command is

Serial.print("Hello");

etc.

However, I see nothing (or garbage) in Energia's Serial Monitor. Having worked with serial ports (but not with USB) I know that there are tons of settings that can mismatch (baud rate and such). What are the defaults for Energia (or for MSP430, if Energia does not change them)?

Next step is to see the input/output on my Windows 7. All I know as far as cmd is "copy con:  com4:" and "copy com4: con:", and I do it in two different cmd windows. That is probably not how to do that. I am going to bite the bullet and download Putty or something, but what's the command-line way to do this?

Just seems that this is such a standard "hello, world" task, and yet I don't find a straighforward way to solve it. Maybe there is a manual.. don't know. My search fetched nothing.

**Edit:** I made it work, for the most part. I am not ready to answer my own question yet, because I don't understand how or why it works.

What I did was this: I set up Energia's port to COM4: in order to upload my code; and to COM3: in order to talk to the launchpad via USB (I presume that's UART) using Serial.println() and such. I don't understand why.

Also, I downloaded Putty and could talk to my device through it; I still don't know how to do the same from command prompt.

Comment: @dwelch, Did you just delete your comments? I saw you mentioned my device has UARTs in plural. What does it mean? Does it have more than one?

Comment: I deleted I saw your edit and I looked up that part at ti Up to Four Universal Serial Communication Interfaces
USCI_A0, USCI_A1, USCI_A2, and USCI_A3 Each Support:
Enhanced UART Supports Auto-Baudrate Detection

Comment: so my comments about do you have a uart are now answered.

Comment: This is pertinent to me, because my next task is to communicate to a bluetooth chip wt32 via UART, and I don't know how to do it, given that the chip is sitting on pt3.3 and pt3.4 pins (tx and rx).

Comment: the older launchpads had no uart on the parts, the current ones the part they include does have one, but you cant access it through the usb, you have to have additional hardware with rx/tx tied to pins.  I dont know what launchpad you have.

Comment: My launchpad model is in subj, and I don't know whether Energia uses software or hardware UART behind the scenes, it's two lines of code for me: Serial.begin(9600); and then Serial.print("Hello");

Comment: the launchpad usb talks to another device on the board (msp430) that we dont get to play with that uses the jtag-ish interface on the msp430 that we do get to play with to program it.   Okay I see now they have new msp430 launchpads that I didnt know about.  will have to buy some.  the exp430g2 one is the the one I am very familiar with

Comment: @dwelch, if you don't mind, please don't delete your comments, your line of thought is very informative for me, even if you later correct yourself. I am learning a lot from it.

Comment: If you get the schematic for that board you will see two parts one connected to the usb and the other is the msp430f55blah, the RXD and TXD from the msp430fblah goes to the other part.  P4.4/UCA1TXD P4.5/UCA1RXD with a jumper if you dont want that to happen.  SBWTCK and SBWTDIO are jtag like and are used to program the msp430f55blah

Comment: MSP430F5528IRGC is on the ezfet page, it is the one we dont play with it is used to help us talk to the one we do play with U6 the MSP430F552x.  I am not familiar with the software you are talking about but directly or indirectly through TI software your hello world was downloaded into the flash on the msp430 (the one we play with) and then released from reset, that program spit the text out the uart which goes to the other part which goes to usb which goes to your computer and putty...

Comment: Just trying to help, you need the schematic which you get from the ti launchpad website for that board, it is in a zip file with the hardware stuff.  trying to finish answering your question "I dont understand how or why it works" just describing how it works from a high level...

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you were answering my question in the comments on how to use second UART to talk to Bluetooth. But perhaps I should make a separate question out of it. I think I should be able to understand what you just said in the morning, with a little googling.

Comment: bluetooth depends on your bluetooth module (unless this has one which I doubt seriously at that price) so if your bluetooth module is serial then setup one of the other uarts, if it is spi then setup a spi port, etc.

Comment: you would then have host to msp430 and msp430 to bluetooth separately, if you wanted of course you could echo the host <-> msp430 to/from the msp430 <-> bluetooth module...

Comment: I still don't see how to do that from Energia. I've started a question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393742/how-to-interface-with-windows-from-msp-exp430f5529lp-via-usb-preferably-from-en?noredirect=1#comment34049951_22393742

Comment: Sorry, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396442/can-i-use-uart-on-msp-exp430f5529lp-from-energia-in-order-to-communicate-on-pins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice, I didnt know they added more boards to their launchpad lineup.  I have multiples of most of their boards will have to go out and get some of this one you have.

this a fancier part, it does have one or more uarts on it.

As with many boards of this type (microcontroller eval boards) there is the device we get to play with and not always but often another device that is directly connected to the usb.  that device we normally dont get touch it communicates with the ide or flash loader tools, etc and then often uses some protocol for the part we play with (jtag, etc) to reprogram that parts flash so we can download programs to it.

The less expensive through hole launchpad board did not have a part with a uart originally it now does but the last time I looked you had to use additional hardware to connect to it.  This board does what is not atypical of this class of boards, the part we play withs uart is connected to the part we dont play withs uart, and via the usb the part we dont play withs uart looks like a serial port to the host and the thing connected to it is the part we play with.

This is how this board is setup so that usb interface is there both to reprogram the msp430 and to give us serial access to it.

Being windows I cannot help you too much I am 99% linux now. putty should work, in the dos days you did the copy con or copy com con type stuff, does that work anymore, I have no idea it has bee a couple of decades since I tried that last.  since you have been successful with putty that means the only unknown is your command line (in theory).  putty, I assume, if not others can log the com port input to a file so the effect is the same other than perhaps not being able to script it.

You may have to just write your own command line program. to read from com and write to file.