# Can I use UART on MSP-EXP430F5529LP from Energia in order to communicate on pins p3.3 and p3.4 (rx and tx respectively)?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, msp430

Can I use UART on  MSP-EXP430F5529LP  from Energia in order to communicate on pins p3.3 and p3.4 (rx and tx respectively)?

I already use UART in order to communicate with my PC via USB. To do so, I use Serial.println() and such. Now that one UART is taken, how do I configure and use second UART to go to these pins? Or would it be better to rewire my Bluetooth chip (BlueGiga wt32) to some other pins?

Configuration aside, Serial does not seem to allow for multiple UARTs. How does it know which UART to print to?

For some reason, I could not find any manual on interacting with wt32 from Energia, or on interacting with multiple UARTs on Energia.

**Edit:** found this link: http://forum.43oh.com/topic/3942-stellaris-lm4f120-multiple-uart-problem/
only, incidentally, they say it does not work. Still, a lead.. but it is my understanding that I still have to configure UART on those two pins, if at all possible.

**Edit2** Found MultiSerial example in Energia:

```
/*
  Multple serial test

  Receives from the main serial port, sends to the others. 
  Receives from serial port 1, sends to the main serial (Serial 0).

  The circuit: 
  * Any serial device attached to Serial port 1
  * Serial monitor open on Serial port 0:

  created 30 Dec. 2008
  by Tom Igoe

  This example code is in the public domain.

*/


void setup() {
  // initialize both serial ports:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read from port 1, send to port 0:
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.write(inByte); 
  }
}
```

Now, this may sound like a really noob question, but *where* is my Serial1?? Is it somewhere on my pinout? The corresponding page in Energia manual is just a stub.

Now, this link: http://energia.nu/Tutorial_SerialCallResponse.html has a pinout according to which P1.1 is TXD, P1.2 is RXSD, which is something that I have not seen documented elsewhere. I suspect that it is assigned in this particular example, only I don't see the assignment in the code; also, I suspect that this is the backchannel, unless the switch is turned. Confused!

**Edit3:** found SoftwareSerial example that turns pins of your choice into a RX and TX. So at least I probably have a software solution. Of course, I'd prefer hardware. The manual for the launchboard says the hardware supports up to 4 serial ports, but how? Where are the pins?

Sorry I keep adding to this. I'll tidy it out when there is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont need those uart pins to talk to the host you can remove the jumpers on that board that connect rxd and txd and then connect those to your bluetooth module.

Comment: Interesting! But I kind of want to talk to the host, because I am still not setup to use a debugger, have no screen, just a blinker.. how else do I debug if I can't print a String?

Comment: BTW, if I remove the jumpers, will it still upload my code via USB?

Comment: I cant help you with energia sorry.  In days or weeks whenver they arrive I will have my MSP-EXP430F5529LP launchpads and will play with them with C/asm and post examples to github...

Comment: yes, in your other question that is what I was describing there are two pins there for reset/jtag and two for rxd/txd and then looks like rts and cts.  the reset/jtag pins are used for programming, rxd/txd should not be involved...easy to test though just pull them and try to program the part...

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you. So, if you were to set up the second UART on the pins I specified using C.. is that even possible? How would you approach that?

Comment: Or maybe there are any *other* pins already configured for UARTs?

Comment: It is my understanding that hardware UART can only be on dedicated UART ports, while software UART can be configured to use any pins? Is that correct?

Comment: 'because I am still not setup to use a debugger' - you should try and fix that ASAP.

Comment: Yes if there are other uarts in the part which I think there are you can use them, they probably do have a short list of pins that are supported for rx and tx for each uart.  TI is pretty good at clearly listing the steps to initialize a device (a uart) so you just walk through those steps setting those registers and there you go.  Yes you can definitely do it in c/asm.  I dont know this other tool you are using but someone somewhere bridged the gap between the program at the level you saw and the registers in the part.  you can perhaps just clone that with a different name Serial1.print()

Comment: sorry just read your edits about Energia, I assume the person that couldnt do it didnt know what they were doing.  They must not have split off the second/third item completely right and had a collision somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Serial.begin(); works for backchannel UART pins(Txd,Rxd between target ic & debugger ic marked in white squares in below image)

http://energia.nu/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/2016-06-09-LaunchPads-MSP432-2.0-%E2%80%94-Pins-Maps.jpg

Serial1.begin(); works for P3_2 & P3_3